# Drupal 8 How to make a view that shows only taxonomy terms related to the current node

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

In drupal 8 I have a content type "article" which has taxonomy terms. Now I would like to make a list of those terms in a block so I can put it somewhere else on the page than the bottom of the node content.

Edit: I tried to follow https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69426/get-list-of-taxonomy-terms-for-current-node-through-views
but I can't select NID in step 4.

Comment: I've tried a view with taxonomy terms with all kinds of relations and contextual filters. I think it must be somewhere in that area, but I can't seem to find the right combination.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69426/get-list-of-taxonomy-terms-for-current-node-through-views
I have tried this, butI can't select NID in step 4 of the answer, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a 'Taxonomy Terms' view, choose block attachment
- Add a relationship, something like 'Content using field_my_taxonomy_term' - in this case you want to use the entity ref field on your 'Article' content type.
- After adding the relationship, add a contextual filter, in this case it will simply be 'ID' for category 'Content': 
  [image: id]
- After adding, configure the relationship field and select 'Provide default value' in the first bullet point:
  [image: filter]

Then that should be it. You can use the 'preview' field to enter a node id and see results in the view itself.

[image: view]

Afterwards, you can add the block to the page you want and voila, the block should work correctly